# Is the problem with individual locks or the remote entry locking system?

Tags: locks, keyless-entry

I have a friend who has a 2000 Mazda 323 who has been experiencing some problems with his door locks.

It started out that when using the keyless entry remote one of the locks wouldn't lock.  Then the problem spread and now he has three locks which won't close with the keyless entry remote.

He took it to a shop and they told him the three locks need to be replaced.  However I asked him if the locks work when he uses the key, and he said all the locks work fine with the key, as in when he inserts the key in the drivers side door.

So based on this, I think the individual locks are probably fine, and there is some problem with the remote entry system.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

**EDIT Nov. 23rd 2016**

I spoke with my friend again, and this is the current situation:

With the remote, only the driver side passenger door locks.

When he closes the driver's door, all doors lock ***except*** the drivers side passenger door.  He is simply closing the door without using the key or remote.

When he locks with the key from the driver's side the two passenger side locks lock.

Further ideas?

Comment: if he hits the switch in the door, do they all work?

Comment: It sounds like the solenoids could be going bad. I'd doubt the locks themselves are. The locks may be getting stiffer, which isn't a replacement issue, but rather a "clean and lubricate" issue.

Comment: @rpmerf I'll ask him tonight if I can get ahold of him.

Comment: I wonder if at 12.5v or whatever when the car is off, the locks are too sticky to work, but at 14v when the car is running, there's enough juice to fight past the stickiness for them to work.

Comment: First thing I'd do is check that fuse box to make sure no fuses are blown.

Answer (score 1):

While multiple lock actuator failures aren't unheard of, I'd suggest checking the wiring to the door switches first. Especially the portion that goes from the cabin to the door.

Also older central locking systems tend to share common splices for power and ground.

Comment: Do my updates to the question change your diagnoses at all?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes I'd be interested in looking at a wiring diagram if you have one. It is an interesting problem. I wonder if the system has a central locking module and if it does I'd like to see if the remote lock portion is incorporated into the module. I'd suggest putting a graphing multimeter or have a helper go through the various locking situations and monitor the output from the module or input at the actuators.

Comment: The Mazda's sold in Israel during those years came installed with a Cobra brand remote entry / alarm system as far as I know.  Are you familiar with those?  That's what my 98 626 had on it.